# 4 simultaneous equations in real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, real-numbers

Solve the following system of equations in real numbers:

$\begin{cases}x^2+zx=y+z\\y^2+xy=z+x\\z^2+yz=x+y\\xyz=1\end{cases}$

Comment: extract the common variable on each left hand side of the first 3 equations (e.g. $x^2 + xz = x(x+z)$) and then substitute corresponding values given in other equations which will lead you to use $xyz=1$

Comment: (1,1,1). I solved it! I assume you want some type of approach... I think looking at it is the fastest method...

Comment: @Mason can you please suggest the way of looking at it?

Comment: @SandroLovnički I don't get your point... Do you mean the last equation is say useless? Yes, I agree

Comment: Spotting solutions like that is something that some math nerds are better at than others but it's the type of thing you look for when you look at too many test questions. Here is the best explanation I can give of how you would "just spot it." 
Instead of using algebraic techniques to solve $3x+4=25$ just ask yourself this: "What number can you triple add $4$ and have it equal $25$? Your mind should settle on the correct answer. Try the same thing with the set of equations above. What number just makes this happen?

Comment: You mean to state that $(1,1,1)$ is the solution and then proof there are no other solutions?

Comment: I was just trying to answer your question of "the way of looking at it" to spot an answer. I am not claiming it's the only solution. To do this we will need some type of algebraic manipulation I would imagine. Sandro Lovnički's suggestion is a good one.

Comment: Ohh. The result itself is straightforwardly affordable. The think is how you prove its the only one.

Comment: Every permutation of the variables leaves the equations unchanged, so look for solutions with $x=y=z$.

Comment: Are you sure all the permutations leave them unchanged? Permutation $(y,x,z)$ differs from $(x,y,z)$

Comment: Vieta's suggests playing with $(x-1)(y-1)(z-1)$

Comment: _Cyclic_ permutations of all three variables, that is.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$, where $v^2$ can be negative,  and $xyz=w^3$.

Thus, $w^3=1$ and after summing of first three equations we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^2+xy)=2(x+y+z)$$ or
$$9u^2-3v^2=6u,$$ which gives $$v^2=3u^2-2u.$$ 
Now, $$(x-y)^2(x-z)^2(y-z)^2\geq0$$ gives
$$3u^2v^4-4v^6-4u^3w^3+6uv^2w^3-w^6\geq0$$ or
$$3u^2(3u^2-2u)^2-4(3u^2-2u)^3-4u^3+6u(3u^2-2u)-1\geq0$$ or
$$(u-1)^2(81u^4-18u^3+15u^2+2u+1)\leq0$$ and since
$$81u^4-18u^3+15u^2+2u+1=u^2(9u-1)^2+(u+1)^2+13u^2>0,$$ we obtain $u=1$, $v^2=1$ and since $x$, $y$ and $z$ they are roots of the equation
$$(t-x)(t-y)(t-z)=0$$ or
$$t^3-3ut^2+3v^2t-w^3=0$$ or $$t^3-3t^2+3t-1=0$$ or $$(t-1)^3=0,$$ we obtain
$$x=y=z=1.$$
Easy to see that these values are valid and we are done!

There is also the following solution.

We'll prove that $$\sum_{cyc}(x^2+xy)\geq2(x+y+z)$$ for all reals $x$, $y$ and $z$ such that $xyz=1$.

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}(x^2+xy)\right)^3\geq8xyz(x+y+z)^3,$$ which is a linear inequality of $w^3$, which says that it's enough to prove our inequality for an extreme value of $w^3$, which happens for an equality case of two variables.

Since the last inequality is even degree and homogeneous, it's enough to assume $y=z=1$, which gives
$$(x-1)^2(x^4+8x^3+28x^2+44x+27)\geq0$$ and since
$$x^4+8x^3+28x^2+44x+27=(x^2+4x+5)^2+2(x+1)^2>0,$$ our inequality is proven.

The equality occurs for $x=y=z$, which gives a solution of our system.

Answer (score 1):

Let us give first the computer aided solution, [sage](http://www.sagemath.org). We associate the corresponding ideal, and ask for an elimination of two variables.

```
sage: R.<x,y,z> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
sage: J = R.ideal( [x*(x+z)-(y+z), y*(y+x)-(z+x), z*(z+y)-(x+y), x*y*z-1] )
sage: J.elimination_ideal( [x,y] )
Ideal (z^7 + z^5 + z^4 + 3*z^3 - 7*z^2 + 2*z - 1) 
    of Multivariate Polynomial Ring in x, y, z over Rational Field

sage: factor( z^7 + z^5 + z^4 + 3*z^3 - 7*z^2 + 2*z - 1 )
(z - 1) * (z^6 + z^5 + 2*z^4 + 3*z^3 + 6*z^2 - z + 1)
```

Now it turns out that the remained polynomial has exactly one real root, $z=1$, all other roots are complex. To see there is no real root, we can write for the quotient 
$$ 
(z^6 + z^5 + 2z^4 + 3z^3 + 6z^2 - z + 1)
$$
as
$$
\underbrace{(z^6+z^5+z^4)}_{\ge 0}
+
\underbrace{(z^4+3z^3+5z^2)}_{\ge 0}
+
\underbrace{(z^2-z+1)}_{> 0}
>0\ .
$$
From this we have solved the problem by symmetry. (We have so far $z=1$, same argument gives by cyclic permutation of variables also $y=1$ and $x=1$, and $x=y=z=1$ is a solution of the algebraic system.)

---

Humanly, we have to work algebrically, but then it is hard to isolate an inequality with more than two variables, so the above elimination may be needed, or we search for some convexity argument for a function in three variables. Here is a way to eliminate as a human.

---

We multiply the given equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x^2+zx &= y+z\\
y^2+xy &= z+x\\
z^2+yz &= x+y\\
xyz &=1
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
with $1,1,x,-1$, add, get an equation of degree one in $x$,
$$
x(z^2+z-1) = -y^2+y+2z-1\ .
$$
From the equations and the above relation:
$$
x = \frac{-y^2+y+2z-1}{z^2+z-1}
=\frac{z-y^2}{y-1}
=\frac 1{yz}\ .
$$
We forget about $x$.
Consider now the last equality as a polynomial equation of degree two in $z$, 
and use the other one to obtain a polynomial identity, then build the rest w.r.t. to the polynomial equation in $z$. The rest / reminder gives the elimination.

---

**Later edit.** This algebraic solution i started is the "standard solution", it is not "beautiful", but it applies in all similar cases, we use dry elimination, and refuse to be "creative". From 
$$
\frac{-y^2+y+2z-1}{z^2+z-1}
=\frac 1{yz}
\text{ and }
\frac{z-y^2}{y-1}
=\frac 1{yz}
$$
we obtain the two equations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
-y^3z + y^2z + 2yz^2 - yz - z^2 - z + 1 &=0\ ,\\
(*)\qquad yz^2 - y^3z  - y + 1 &=0\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(Now we build the resultant of the above polynomials of the L.H.S., seen as polynomials in $z$, or we work ad-hoc as follows.) From the second equation, we extract $\displaystyle z^2 = y^2 z + 1 +\frac 1y$, and insert in the first equation. All $z^2$-terms will be replaced. (This is the same as a polynomial division with rest.) We get:
$$
y^4z - y^2z + 2y^2 - yz - 2y + 1=0\ .
$$
This gives a formula for $z$ in terms of $y$:
$$
z=-\frac{2y^2 - 2y + 1}{y^4-y^2-y}\ .
$$
We insert this value in the equation $(*)$, this leads to... (computation done here with the computer)

```
sage: Z = -(2*y^2 - 2*y + 1) / y / (y^3 - y - 1)
sage: factor( y*Z^2 - y^3*Z - y + 1 )
y^-1 * (y - 1)^2 * (y^3 - y - 1)^-2 * (y^6 + y^5 + 2*y^4 + 3*y^3 + 6*y^2 - y + 1)
```

The only way to make the numerator vanish is via $y=1$. This gives then $z=1$, and finally $x=1$.

Comment: I don't really understand the last part of your solution. Can you please explain it?

Comment: I tried to fill in details, only dry computations, of course. (The human idea is elimination, this is supported by sage for instance, one can require the elimination steps - only $x$, or both $x,y$  as wanted.)

Answer (score 0):

Making $y = \nu x, z = \mu x$ we have

$$
x = \frac{\nu+\mu}{1+\mu} = \frac{\mu+1}{\nu(\nu+1)}=\frac{1+\nu}{\mu(\mu+1)}
$$

Giving the two systems

$$
\frac{\nu+\mu}{1+\mu} = \frac{\mu+1}{\nu(\nu+1)}\\
\frac{\mu+1}{\nu(\nu+1)}=\frac{1+\nu}{\mu(\mu+1)}
$$

and

$$
\frac{\nu+\mu}{1+\mu} = \frac{\mu+1}{\nu(\nu+1)}\\
\frac{\nu+\mu}{1+\mu}=\frac{1+\nu}{\mu(\mu+1)}
$$

solving for $\nu, \mu$ we get as the solutions intersection

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\nu & \mu\\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

and the real solution is $\nu = \mu = 1$ with $x=y=z=1$

Attached a plot showing the three intervinent independent equalities.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this approach is something the OP understands or is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have something.  Vieta's equations with $(x-1)(y-1)(z-1)$

Expanding gives roughly the same as adding the 3 equations together. Swapping in the above and cancelling terms we find:

$$X(x-1)+y(y-1)+z(z-1)=(x-1)(y-1)(z-1)$$

$$(X-1/2)^2+(y-1/2)^2+(z-1/2)^2=(x-1)(y-1)(z-1)+3/4$$

We read off (1,1,1)

Solutions lie on a spheres centered at (1/2,1/2,1/2)  that intersect a hyperboloid defined on the right. Let R be a given radius from the center of the sphere.

$R^2=(x-1)(y-1)(z-1)+3/4$
If $x=y=z$, then $x=(r^2-3/4)^{1/3}+1$

The hyperboloid has axis the line where x=y=z.

More possible solutions can be found using cylindrical symmetry.